# what am I doing wrong here? Registration with devise and adding a role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    if resource.save
      if request.fullpath == '/techie/signup'
         resource.role = :techie
         resource.save
      end  
    end  
  end

end
```

I have this overriding the devise controller and I have a separate sign up view with a path of '/techie/signup/' and I want to add a role to the user based on the page they signed up on. I do not want to put the role in a hidden field as that stuff can be exploited.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code to see how far the data makes it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
  def create
    super do |res|
      if request.path_info == '/techie/signup'
         res.role = :techie
         res.save!
      end  
    end  
  end
```

Comment: getting a undefined method `fullpath' guessing would need to include the helpers in the model but doesnt that break MVC?

Comment: @SaraAl let me test on mine, im not sure `res` object provides fullpath.

Comment: thanks! haven't really found much other than people editing the role based on a hidden field and don't think it's best for security, better just set it based on the URL path

Comment: @SaraAl I just updated my post, check that one. that was my bad actually.

Comment: @SaraAl, Also, Do not forget to add strong params to devise for `role` data.

Comment: Yes, I did add the role for strong params however it's still not setting the role unfortunately.

Comment: @SaraAl Try `res.role = 'yeah worked' ` because i dnt know whats behind `:techie` probably thats why gives error. Also would be great if u post `server log` after submitting it.

Comment: There isn't an error, it's just not setting the role.

Comment: I have a role column for the user and I am setting it with the enum functionality of rails 4 . In my user model I have  enum role: [:user, :techie, :admin]

Comment: I figured it out, had to use this since it turns out to be a previous URL: URI(request.referer).path

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using request.full_path or request.path_info, using

```
URI(request.referer).path
```

solved it.

Comment: nice, but what exactly returns  this  `URI(request.referer).path` ?

Comment: @7urkm3n it returns '/techie/signup' on the create method of the registration controller. Turns out grabbing the current path not correlating with the create action of registration doesn't actually still mean '/techie/signup' is the current path. It was the prior path and request.referer grabs the last page.